# Double Connect Wall - I'll Drink to That!

Tags: connect-wall

This is my first attempt at a Connect Wall. Your task is to find the connections between the following 16 words to form 8 groups of 4. *No, I did not Muck up the Fath* – there is one connection per row and one connection per column

**Fun fact**: I’ve recently been car-pooling with a work colleague and thanks to his efforts I have learnt how the British quiz show works. But rot13(obl qb V fhpx ng guvf tnzr)

Good luck!

**EDIT: This was harder than expected so I will add a few hints, sorted in order of increasing desperation (great phrase from the [Perl manual pages](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/perl-doc/perldiag.1.en.html) btw! ) :**

HINT 1

> The horizontal connections seem “kinda lame” but the point of the puzzle becomes clear once you think about vertical connections. Solving these vertical connections will reveal the point of the puzzle title (Equivalently one can transpose horizontal/vertical grouping and the result is the same).

HINT 2

> The vertical connections are a “puzzle within a puzzle” if you will!

HINT 3

> The connections are based on wordplay/numbers rather than general knowledge. I can crush most episodes of Letters And Numbers but would totally embarrass myself on Mastermind or WWTBAM

[image: digit, braver, nonet, twice, foxtail, friendly, alphyl, heavenly, siesta, letter, unit, greatly, finely, hexagon, bottle, inch]

Comment: "there is one connection per row and one connection per column" - does that mean in its *current* configuration, or do we have to rearrange the words to make this the case?

Comment: We have to rearrange the words to make this the case

Answer (score 3):

New answer (with guesses for all 8 categories, revised after feedback):

> `| FRIENDLY | HEAVENLY | FINELY  | GREATLY |`
>  `| UNIT     | ALPHYL   | SIESTA  | FOXTAIL |`
>  `| TWICE    | BRAVER   | INCH    | BOTTLE  |`
>  `| LETTER   | HEXAGON  | NONET   | DIGIT   |`
>
>  Row 1: Words ending in "ly", i.e. adverbs
>  Row 2: First three letters match the NATO alphabet (uniform, alfa/"alpha", sierra, foxtrot)
>  Row 3: Can replace 2nd letter to form new word (trice, beaver, itch, battle)
>  Row 4: Multiple units (letter = 26, hexagon = 6, nonet = 9, digit = 10)
>
>  Column 1: "Hot" phrases (friendly fire, burn unit, twice baked, letter bomb)
>  Column 2: First 2 letters + last letter form a word (hey, all, brr, hen)
>  Column 3: Replace one consonant to form a new word (finery, fiesta, itch, monet)
>  Column 4: Prefix + suffix makes a new word (grey, foil/fail, bole, dit)
>
>  Note that columns 2 and 4 are quite similar so I'm not very confident about those

Previous iteration (see happystar's comments for feedback):

> `| HEAVENLY | FRIENDLY | FINELY  | GREATLY |`
>  `| FOXTAIL  | BRAVER   | SIESTA  | UNIT    |`
>  `| BOTTLE   | ALPHYL   | INCH    | LETTER  |`
>  `| DIGIT    | HEXAGON  | NONET   | TWICE   |`
>
>  Row 1: Words ending in "ly", i.e. adverbs
>  Row 2: First three letters match the NATO alphabet (foxtrot, bravo, sierra, uniform)
>  Row 3: Singular units (one bottle, alphyl = univalent radical, one inch, one letter)
>  Row 4: Multiple units (digit = 10, hexagon = 6, nonet = 9, twice = 2)
>
>  Column 1: Prefix for a plant (heavenly bamboo, foxtail lily, bottlebrush, digitalis)
>  Column 2: First 2 letters + last letter form a word (fry, brr, all, hen).  Note: nonet could swap with hexagon
>  Columns 3/4: Unknown (can swap words in these columns)
>
>  I'm only confident in the four rows and column 1.
>  I need help figuring out columns 2-4.

Comment: rot13(svefg ebj vf shyyl pbeerpg, nyy bgure ebjf ner nyzbfg pbeerpg, svefg pbyhza vf jebat - havagraqrq erq ureevat!)

Comment: @happystar rot13(Vs ebj 2 va jebat, gur bayl pnaqvqngr vf nyculy juvpu vfa'g rknpgyl n cersvk sbe "nysn".  Vf gung vagraqrq?  Nyfb, vf pbyhza 2 jebat?)

Comment: rot13(v'ir frra nycun vafgrnq bs nysn sbe gur cubargvp nycunorg. Nyfb pbyhza 2 vf vaqrrq jebat)

Comment: @happystar OK, how about the latest answer, how many rows/columns are correct?

Comment: rot13(bayl gur svefg ebj vf pbeerpg). Actually I'm kinda regretting posting this puzzle too hastily and wish I had aimed for perfection rather than speed - but it's probably too late to edit this puzzle and risk giving away something too easily. Any thoughts re editing this puzzle?

Comment: @happystar Since I don't know the solution I can't really say whether the puzzle was too hastily constructed.  It seems like I am close to solving the rows but I'm not finding any connections in the columns.  Whatever groupings there are don't seem as tangible as the ones I found for rows 1-2.  Maybe some hints would help.  Also, even if my rows/columns aren't correct, are any of the categories correct or being close to correct?

Comment: in response to @JS1's answer rot13(nyy pngrtbevrf ner pbeerpg rkprcg fvathyne havgf)

Comment: @happystar BTW My answer has been edited, there are 2 guesses: a new one and the original one.  Are any of the new guesses any closer?

Comment: this is getting further away since one of the rows is now 2/4 correct instead of 3/4 correct. Also rot13(zhygvcyr havgf fubhyq or ahzoref yrff guna gra)